# Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes for external jar files In android project

Tags: java, android, security, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I added external jar as dependency in android project but I am facing below error. my jar structure is like

[image]

```
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.SecurityException: java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
```

I added below line in my build gradle files but still issue not resolve:

```
 packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
    exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
    exclude 'META-INF'


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed when I used unsigned jar.

Comment: how do you accomplish this?

Comment: @Jitendra : How do you resolve this when using signed jar?